# How can I disconnect a stove top burner from an infinite switch?

Tags: oven, range-hood

I have an old Kenmore stove and the back left burner will not turn off.  I am assuming this is an issue with the infinite switch - I don't want to spend the money to replace the switch I would rather just disconnect it.

I can identify the five wires going into the switch (L1, L2, H1, H2, P)

I want to just disconnect the switch so the burner does not get power.  Is there a way to safely disconnect the switch?  I would like to disconnect at the switch without digging too far into the oven, but I also am not sure how to properly cap the two 120v wires in an area that is going to get hot.

The stove model is 790.46351400
The infinite switch part number is 318220080

My questions are:

1. Can I leave the line wires in and unplug H1 and H2 to disable the burner?
2. Is there a wire cap I can use for L1 and L2 so I can remove the switch all together and safely use the oven?

Comment: Model number of the stove and/or pictures of the wiring in question would be really helpful.

Comment: @FreeMan is correct (as usual) - the type of wire cap and whether better to cap line vs. switched wires may vary by model and type of wire.

Comment: Old kenmore probably rules out induction, but leaves the coil .vs. glass/ceramic top question open. The problem is trivially solved if coil. [Edit] to tell or show us what kind this one is and which specific model number it is.

Comment: edited to add model and part number @FreeMan

Comment: Honest question: What's an "infinite switch"? Is that one where you can position it anywhere from "barely on" to "full heat", instead of having some fixed steps in between? I don't know that I've ever seen a burner control knob with a series of fixed steps...

Comment: @FreeMan "infinite switch" is the industry term, and it *is* not good termonology. They mean continuously variable.

Answer (score 3):

If "Old Kenmore Stove" = electric coil elements, remove the element - takes 5 seconds and you can't turn it on if it's not there. Throw a burner cover over the empty hole. Put the coil in the drawer under the oven, or behind the drawer under the oven if you have a bunch of things you use in there. It will be handy enough if you ever want it again. *(Just guess where my canning element is in the off season)*

Comment: The stove model is 790.46351400
The infinite switch part number is 318220080

There is a glass top over the elements so I would need to remove that to pull out whatever is underneath.  My concern in either case (removing switch or element) would be the live wires - if the infinite switch is stuck in the 'on' position then presumably there would be two 120v active wires just sitting there in the stove

Comment: You know where the infinite switch is. Look up on youtube replacement of infinite switch  which will tell you how to get to the switch. Disconnect the two line hot wires from the switch and wrap the ends with electrical tape or heatshrink to insulate the ends. If the controls are at the back above, pull stove out away from wall and open back panel with screws. Of course turn off breaker first.

Comment: The stove ON indicator light is also presumably ON ("P" label) so you should also disconnect that wire from the infinite switch and tape it up also.

Answer (score 1):

You know where the infinite switch is.* Look up on youtube replacement of infinite switch  which will tell you how to get to the switch. Disconnect the two line hot wires from the switch and wrap the ends with electrical tape or heatshrink to insulate the ends. Leave the insulated ends nearby. Put back panel back and tighten screws. Check operation before you push th estove back in place.

*If the controls are at the back above, pull stove out away from wall and open back panel with screws. Of course turn off breaker first. At this point why not get a replacement and put it in, even if you think you won't really need it. You can get replacement online or from a YouFixit type local outlet.

If the infinite switches are in front low you may find it more difficult to get to the infinite switch but still should not be too hard.

EDIT

Also disconnect the wire to the stove ON indicator light ("P"?) and tape it up so it cannot contact something.

EDIT2

Of course, the two line hot wire ends are to be taped individually so they cannot contact each other!

Answer (score 0):

Simply pulling the connector attached to terminal H1 or H2 from the switch will disable the burner. It will likely be a female 1/4" quick disconnect, which can be insulated by wrapping a few times with electrical tape. Usually the area immediately adjacent to the switch will not present temperature problems, but if so you could use a high-temp electrical tape, such as those made of glass cloth.

Comment: You would also want to remove the "P" lead if it is activating the "pilot" or indicator light which is on if any burner is on.